# How can I submit a PHP form post and redirect to a confirmation page in one step?

Tags: php, forms, post, submit

I have a PHP form, from which I need to submit POST data to a third-party URL and redirect to a confirmation page.

I have no control over the third-party page and that provides no confirmation after POST, so I need to add that into my code.

Here is the process in more detail:

PHP form on www.example-site-1.com/form.php, which uses basic htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); to perform validation, before redirecting:

```
<?php
// Setup Empty Fields
$first_name = $last_name = $job_title = "";

// Setup Empty Error Messages
$first_nameError = $last_nameError = $job_titleError = "";

// Validate Field Entry
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    $valid = true; // Redirect if valid

    if (empty($_POST["first_name"]))
    {$valid = false; $first_nameError = "Provide first name";}
        else
        {$first_name = htmlspecialchars($_POST["first_name"]);}

    if (empty($_POST["last_name"]))
    {$valid = false; $last_nameError = "Provide surname";}
        else
        {$last_name = htmlspecialchars($_POST["last_name"]);}

    if (empty($_POST["job_title"]))
    {$valid = false; $job_titleError = "Provide your job title";}
        else
        {$job_title = htmlspecialchars($_POST["job_title"]);}

// Start session
session_start();

// Register session
session_register('first_name');
session_register('last_name');
session_register('job_title');

// Populate
$_SESSION['first_name'] = $first_name;
$_SESSION['last_name'] = $last_name;
$_SESSION['job_title'] = $job_title; 

// Redirect valid form to process
if($valid)
    {header('Location: process.php');
exit();
}
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>

        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" name="submit_data" method="POST" id="submit_data">

            <fieldset>
                <legend>Your Details</legend>
                    <p><label for="first_name">First Name</label><input type="text" id="first_name" size="20" maxlength="50" value="<?php echo $first_name;?>" name="[first_name]" /><br /><span class="error"> <?php echo $first_nameError;?></span></p>
                    <p><label for="last_name">Surname</label><input type="text" id="last_name" size="20" maxlength="50" value="<?php echo $last_name;?>" name="[last_name]" /><br /><span class="error"> <?php echo $last_nameError;?></span></p>
                    <p><label for="job_title">Job Title</label><input type="text" id="job_title" size="30" maxlength="30" value="<?php echo $job_title;?>" name="[job_title]" /><br /><span class="error"> <?php echo $job_titleError;?></span></p>
            </fieldset>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've added sessions to carry over into the subsequent page, but perhaps I don't need these. Also, the {header('Location: process.php'); is there for example, but that is really what I am stuck on; how should I perform the following?

Essentially, once somebody clicks Submit, I need 2 things to happen (both from the one click):

1) Form data is submitted to a third-party site (for demo purposes, www.example-site-2.com/submit.php) using POST. User should never see that page (it is a plain white screen, with no feedback provided to the user).

2) User that clicked submit should be transferred to a thank you/confirmation page on www.example-site-1.com/thanks.php

Is this possible?

As mentioned, I unfortunately have no access to edit the third-party site, so cannot add a confirmation after POST on that site.

PHP solution would be great, or JavaScript would be fine.

Any help or ideas much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Use cURL to `POST` the data from your script.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you are trying to acheive here. My understanding is that you want to validate the POST parameters on your site before POSTing them to another site. You can't POST in a redirect. Your only options are to cary out the POST from the server using curl or send the user to a temporary page served by your code containing a populated form and POST from the browser via a button or javascript.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the swift reply. I need to do the validation before submission, as I can edit nothing on the destination form. However, I do know which fields are required, so I'm adding that in, in order that the user is prompted if they fail to enter the required info. Only once all fields are populated should the form submit to the third party. The third-party page has to receive the POST data, but doesn't provide any visible validation or feedback after POST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the POST request yourself, using curl for instance.

```
//set POST variables
$url = 'http://domain.com/get-post.php'; //URL of that site with a blank page
$fields = array( //your parameters here
                        'lname' => urlencode($last_name),
                        'fname' => urlencode($first_name),
                        'title' => urlencode($title),
                        'company' => urlencode($institution),
                        'age' => urlencode($age),
                        'email' => urlencode($email),
                        'phone' => urlencode($phone)
                );

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed example. Would I submit my current form to this, in a separate file, or could I add this in beneath the validation in the head section?

Comment: You should put this code in `if($valid){[here]}` in place of `header(...)`

Comment: Thanks Loïc - I'll combine your suggestion and Daniel's suggestion and see if I get it to redirect as I need. I will feedback ASAP. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use cURL? Something like this I think could do the trick

```
// Where to make our request (third party site)
$ch = curl_init($urlToThirdParty);

// Make the request
curl_exec($ch);

// Did anything went wrong=
if (curl_errno($ch)) {

die('Oops: ' . curl_error($ch));
} else {
// Make sure we got a 200 back (indicating success)
$httpStatusCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if ($httpStatusCode != 200) {
    die('Oops. Status code: ' . $httpStatusCode);
}
}
curl_close($ch);

// If we made it this far, redirect to thank you page
header('Location: '.$thankYouURL);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks - I'll combine your suggestion and Loïc's suggestion and see if I get it to redirect correctly. I will feedback ASAP. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you just send the user to the third party site (as you are doing now) then there is no getting them back.

There are 2 ways that come to mind, 1 submit the form request to the third party site using ajax, grab the response, and then redirect the user to the thanks page on your site.

Or, if you don't want to use javascript, have the form submit to your thanks page, then have some php in there that submits the form request to the third party site (using curl) before displaying the thanks content

Answer (score 0):

What you should do I think is:

create a random token (a random number) and save it in a `$_SESSION['user_token']`.

```
$_SESSION['user_token'] = random_number(); // random_number() is a custom function which generates a random number of some length
```

Then saves the data returned from the form to a database. Your table must have a column called "token_value" or "user_token". When the user returns to you page, check the session with the database:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM form_data WHERE token_value = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_SESSION['user_token']);
// and the rest of DB-related operation
```